# Confessing to Adultery

Tags: mishna, capital-punishment, arayot, tractate-sotah, sotah-secluded-woman

In the Mishna, [Sotah 1:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Sotah.1.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) and [3:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Sotah.3.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) both speak of instances in which a woman suspected of having committed adultery admits of her crime before drinking the water. Given that the penalty for adultery is death (eg: [Leviticus 20:10](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.20.10?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), [Sanhedrin 11:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Sanhedrin.11.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), etc), and given that the curse of the bitter waters might not take effect immediately (cf: [Sotah 3:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Sotah.3.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)), under what circumstances would a guilty woman confess to her crime? Since there are no witnesses, would not every woman choose to take her chances with the water?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If she confesses she won't be put to death by Beis Din since you need 2 witnesses for that.

And if there are 2 witnesses then she won't be tested by the sota water, hence there are not 2 witnesses. We don't execute a person based on his own testimony (Rambam, [Hilkhot Sanhedrin 18:6](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_The_Sanhedrin_and_the_Penalties_within_their_Jurisdiction.18.6?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=he); see also [Yevamot 25b](https://www.sefaria.org/Yevamot.25b.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)), and we don't include an admission with another witness to make two witnesses ([Tosefta Shevuot 5:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Tosefta_Shevuot.5.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)).

Therefore, she would be saving her life from the water by confessing and would not be executed by beis din.

Comment: That makes sense... although it does seem counter-intuitive. Do you have a source for the idea that a person cannot testify against herself? Or that you cannot execute somebody whose admission precedes testimony against them?

Comment: @ShimonbM אין אדם משים עצמו רשע

Comment: For the benefit of others, the statement that @DoubleAA just shared is from Yevamot 25b, and concerns a person's disqualify himself from testimony. Interestingly, the explicit formulation that we do not execute a person on his own testimony appears not to have been stated in so many words until the Rambam, Hilkhot Sanhedrin 18:6. There are, however, similar rulings, and ones from which it might be derived (such as the fact that we don't include a person's testimony with a single witness in order to make two; Tosefta Shevuot 5:3).